# Mobile menu button does not stay inside the navigation

Tags: html, css

With the code below I want to create a **mobile menu button** `<container>` inside my `<navigation>`. All this works fine so far.

However, somehow the mobile menu button does not stay **inside** the `<nav>` .
 *(See the green container compared to the yellow navigation)*

I am guessing it has something to do with the **fixed px** for the width and the height. However, when I change those to a %-width the bars completely dissapear.

What do I have to change in my code so the `<container>` remains inside the surrounding `<nav>`?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p6dqLLj6/3/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: green;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: #333;
 margin: 6px 0;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
  <nav class="navigation"> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div> 
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `height: 10%;` from `.header`, it's taking `10%` height of `html`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  /* height: 10%; */
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: green;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: #333;
 margin: 6px 0;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
  <nav class="navigation"> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div> 
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks a lot for your answer. I also found responsive solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/p6dqLLj6/16/. The only thing I cannot get done so far is that the mobile menu button appears in vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

The margin settings for the bar and the bar itself are too high. Try the CSS below

```
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 3px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```